# Running 2 queries sequentially using cursor.execute for MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a script that does 2 things :
a) It reads a csv file (bank transactions) and populates a transactions table in a MySQL database.
b) Additional columns in the transaction table are updated based on the transaction description mapped to a mapping file (debit category, credit category etc)

Following is my script

```
import mysql.connector as msql
import pandas as pd
from mysql.connector import Error

transdata = pd.read_csv('updt_stat.csv', index_col=False, delimiter=',')
transdata.fillna(0, inplace=True)
transdata = transdata.sort_values('Txn Date')

try:
    conn = msql.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = 'root',
    database = 'npalace'  
    )
    if conn.is_connected:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        print('Database Connected !')
except Error as e:
    print("Error connecting database", e)

for i,row in transdata.iterrows():
    sql = "INSERT INTO npalace.t_bank_pnb (txn_no, txn_date, descr, branch_name, cheque_no, \
        dr_amount, cr_amount, balance, updated_on) VALUES (%s,STR_TO_DATE(%s,'%d-%m-%Y'),%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,curdate())"
    cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
    print('Record Inserted')
    conn.commit() 

sql1 = """
            UPDATE npalace.t_bank_pnb
            JOIN npalace.map_pnb ON npalace.map_pnb.descript LIKE CONCAT('%', npalace.t_bank_pnb.descr, '%')
            SET
                npalace.t_bank_pnb.dr_category = npalace.map_pnb.dr_cat,
                npalace.t_bank_pnb.cr_category = npalace.map_pnb.cr_cat,
                npalace.t_bank_pnb.flat_no = npalace.map_pnb.flat_num
            WHERE npalace.t_bank_pnb.updated_on = CURDATE()
        """   

cursor.execute(sql1)
conn.commit()

conn.close()

print(cursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
```

When I run the script, the first script - sql is run perfectly. However, the second script does not run or there is no change in the table.

I have ensured that all the related tables are there in the database. I also have the csv formatted properly (can share it if required).

I believe the problem might be in the syntax of second query. This query takes a description string from the transactions table and looks if it has any substring from another mapping table. When the match occurs, it picks up the other fields and copies them back to the transactions table.

Can someone please help me with the right way to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the error after a bit of research.

My hunch was right that this was a script error. The correct SQL query is as follows :

```
sql1 = """
   UPDATE npalace.t_bank_pnb
   JOIN npalace.map_pnb 
   SET npalace.t_bank_pnb.dr_category = npalace.map_pnb.dr_cat,
       npalace.t_bank_pnb.cr_category = npalace.map_pnb.cr_cat,
       npalace.t_bank_pnb.flat_no = npalace.map_pnb.flat_num
   WHERE npalace.t_bank_pnb.updated_on = CURDATE()
     AND npalace.t_bank_pnb.descr LIKE CONCAT('%', npalace.map_pnb.descript, '%')
"""
```

The key was to include the substring comparison in a `WHERE` operator.